How does the lambda work? How does it know to call the functional interface? I want details because nothing I've seen explains it well
This is in a javafx program and it runs.
button.setOnAction(_ ->{
    int side = 0;
    Random rand = new Random();
    side = rand.nextInt(2);
    if(side == 0){
       //code here
    else{
       //code here
    }
});

A long version of this functionality would be to create the class that implements the EventHandler. Then create a instance of that class for the button.setOnAction. I do not understand how the lambda works the same as the longer code below. How does it know to use the EventHandler functional interface. I watched many YouTube videos that do not go into the details which is why I ask here.
class Handler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        int side = 0;
        Random rand = new Random();
        side = rand.nextInt(2);
        if(side == 0){

        }
        else{

        }
    }
}


Because the signature of button.setOnAction is button.setOnAction(EventHandler<ActionEvent>).

Brian Goetz elaborates in this answer.

A lambda expression is simply syntax for implementing a functional interface (an interface with a single abstract method). They provide a less verbose way of implementing such interfaces so that you don't have to write a named or anonymous class. But ultimately, a class is created that implements the functional interface; you just don't see it in the source code. Though just like with an anonymous class, a lambda is both the implementation of an interface and an instantiation of that implementation. In your code, an actual object whose class implements EventHandler is created at runtime.

How the compiler knows EventHandler<ActionEvent> is the functional interface being implemented is explained by Elliott's comment—it can infer the type from the context.

Also note that the setOnAction method, at a fundamental level, simply takes the object passed to it as an argument—which must be an implementation of EventHandler<ActionEvent>—and adds it to a collection. Whenever the button receives an ActionEvent, the code will iterate that collection and invoke each appropriate handler's handle method. Research the observer pattern for more information.
